# bash.profile unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: bash

I have a problem with the console when opened lists like this.

I cannot advise with it

-bash: /Users/name/.bash_profile: line 50: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/name/.bash_profile: line 51: syntax error: unexpected end of file

My bash profile looks like this. Please help me

```
# Add `~/bin` to the `$PATH`
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH";
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin:$PATH";
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH”

# Load the shell dotfiles, and then some:
# * ~/.path can be used to extend `$PATH`.
# * ~/.extra can be used for other settings you don’t want to commit.
for file in ~/.{path,bash_prompt,exports,aliases,functions,extra}; do
    [ -r "$file" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && source "$file";
done;
unset file;

# Case-insensitive globbing (used in pathname expansion)
shopt -s nocaseglob;

# Append to the Bash history file, rather than overwriting it
shopt -s histappend;

# Autocorrect typos in path names when using `cd`
shopt -s cdspell;

# Enable some Bash 4 features when possible:
# * `autocd`, e.g. `**/qux` will enter `./foo/bar/baz/qux`
# * Recursive globbing, e.g. `echo **/*.txt`
for option in autocd globstar; do
    shopt -s "$option" 2> /dev/null;
done;

# Add tab completion for many Bash commands
if which brew > /dev/null && [ -f "$(brew --prefix)/share/bash-completion/bash_completion" ]; then
    source "$(brew --prefix)/share/bash-completion/bash_completion";
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    source /etc/bash_completion;
fi;

# Enable tab completion for `g` by marking it as an alias for `git`
if type _git &> /dev/null && [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
    complete -o default -o nospace -F _git g;
fi;

# Add tab completion for SSH hostnames based on ~/.ssh/config, ignoring wildcards
[ -e "$HOME/.ssh/config" ] && complete -o "default" -o "nospace" -W "$(grep "^Host" ~/.ssh/config | grep -v "[?*]" | cut -d " " -f2- | tr ' ' '\n')" scp sftp ssh;

# Add tab completion for `defaults read|write NSGlobalDomain`
# You could just use `-g` instead, but I like being explicit
complete -W "NSGlobalDomain" defaults;

# Add `killall` tab completion for common apps
complete -o "nospace" -W "Contacts Calendar Dock Finder Mail Safari iTunes SystemUIServer Terminal Twitter" killall;
```

Comment: what happens if  you remove all of the extraneous quoting, like single quotes and backticks from your comments? Seems like just asking for trouble (yes, it shouldn't matter, but seems the most likely cause of the problem problem). ELSE repost your code with line numbers. We don't want to have to count 50 lines of code to see where the problem is terminating ;-) Good luck!

Comment: `... "$(grep "^Host" ~/.ssh/config | grep -v "[?*]" | cut -d " " -f2- | tr ' ' '\n')" ...` looks suspect. What happens if you copy/paste that line on the cmd-line? Good luck.

Comment: You have a "smart quote" on the third `export PATH` line at the top. At least in this paste. http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend here. It catches that and a few other errors (like `~` in double quotes which doesn't work).

Comment: Also you don't need to `export` a variable more than once and `PATH` is almost certainly exported for you already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH”
```

The last character in your code is not a `"` but a `”`. This confuses bash.

Comment: I'd say it confuses the reader more than `bash`, which simply keeps building a string because it hasn't yet encountered a `"` to match the first one.

Comment: Well, it's hard to "confuse" a program until we get true A.I., anyways, so forgive my choice of words. :)

Comment: Thank you guys, you are amazing. I couldn't figure it out, my eye didn't catch this little mistake. Many thanks again :)